# Qt - Get the time span between two datetime objects

Tags: c++, qt

I have two datetime objects, say, "2013-06-13 11:00:45", "2013-06-14 09:03:23".

How can I get the time span between these two datetimes(in the form of "X days, X hours, X minutes, X seconds")?

Comment: Simple alternative is TimeDelta class for Qt:
https://github.com/cardinalby/time_delta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you must use [`QDateTime::secsTo`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html#secsTo) and then do the math to figure out the days, hours, minutes and seconds.

However, there are plans to add a `QTimeSpan` class to Qt:

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/1014

It isn't clear when this will get added to Qt; the merge request is almost 2 years old already.  However, you can grab the code from the above merge request and compile it into your project if you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

[`QTime`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime-2) may help to format the part of the result of [`QDateTime::secsTo` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo) ([mentioned by @RA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078714/4279)) that is less than a day e.g., [`t.toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz")`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString) or:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTime>

/// seconds as "X days, X hours, X minutes, X seconds" string
QString secondsToString(qint64 seconds)
{
  const qint64 DAY = 86400;
  qint64 days = seconds / DAY;
  QTime t = QTime(0,0).addSecs(seconds % DAY);
  return QString("%1 days, %2 hours, %3 minutes, %4 seconds")
    .arg(days).arg(t.hour()).arg(t.minute()).arg(t.second());
}
```

Example:

```
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>   

int main()
{
  QString format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  QDateTime a = QDateTime::fromString("2013-06-13 11:00:45", format);
  QDateTime b = QDateTime::fromString("2013-06-14 09:03:23", format);
  qDebug() << secondsToString(a.secsTo(b));
}
```

Output:

```
"0 days, 22 hours, 2 minutes, 38 seconds"
```

By default, the dates use your local timezone. [`QDateTime::secsTo()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo) converts the dates to "seconds since epoch" before finding the difference i.e., if there is a DST transition between the dates or the UTC offset has changes for any other reason then it is taken into account (if the corresponding [C mktime()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) supports it on a given platform). POSIX time does not count leap seconds (you could use a "right" timezone, to count leaps seconds).